# how to escape @ in javascript or how to retrieve data from a field containing @

Tags: javascript, object, special-characters, decorator, reserved

I am retrieving data from an API and one of the fields in the object it returns is @timestamp. When ever I try to parse this data like `item.@timestamp` javascript throws an error because the @ symbol is reserved as a decorator. How can I retrieve data from a field that is using a reserved character?

Comment: Don't use reserved characters in field names/ids? Joking, kind of. Your answer is already below... just saying, if possible, avoid the problem by following standards.

Comment: @TCooper I didn't write the API that I'm retrieving data from :p

Comment: Wow, clearly only half read that first part... amazing what selective attention can do. Tell those API devs to follow standards ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `item['@timestamp']` instead of `item.@timestamp`.

Comment: yep thats the trick thank you! I honestly tried bracket notation but haven't used it in a while and forgot that it required quotes..

Answer (score 1):

Try using bracket notation instead:

```
item['@timestamp']
```

Hopefully that helps!